# haproxy - Route Request and keep same base URL

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I'm new to haproxy and I'm struggling a little bit trying to configure it.

What I want:

1. Type in the browser: proxy.company.com/Test/App
2. Have haproxy balance the request between webapp01.company.com/Test/App and
   webapp02.company.com/Test/App
3. Keep the base URL proxy.company.com/Test/App

What I have so far:
I have two websites setup:

1. webapp01.company.com/Test/App
2. webapp02.company.com/Test/App

Both work and when I browse to each individually I get a screen with the name of the server that served the request (WebApp01 or WebApp02).

However, when I go to proxy.company.com/Test/App I get a 404 error. I expect the request to be routed to webapp01 or webapp02 and I expect to see the name of the server serving the request.

Here's my current configuration:

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend proxy.company.com
   bind :80
acl test_app path_end -i /Test/App

use_backend srvs_test    if test_app

backend srvs_test
   balance roundrobin
   server webapp01 webapp01.company.com:80 check
   server webapp02 webapp02.company.com:80 check
```

If I change the backend configuration to this:

```
backend srvs_test
   balance roundrobin
   redirect location http://webapp01.company.com/Test/App
```

It works, however, if I type proxy.company.com/Test/App I'm redirected to webapp01.company.com/Test/App. The base URL is changed and I want it to remain proxy.company.com/Test/App

Is it possible? How chan I change the configuration to allow what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reverse proxy will by default rewrite the Location header so there is no need for to to do that.

Use `path_beg` instead of `path_end`.

I think your config is too minimal. What happens when you hit `proxy.company.com`? You are missing a `default_backend`.

Also, the whole idea of the proxy is that you don't have to expose webapp01 and 02 to the world. No need to give them external IPs as your example shows with those DNS entries. Just use the internal ones reachable from your proxy.

Try something like:

```
frontend proxy.company.com *:80
  acl test_app path_beg -i /Test/App
  use_backend srvs_test if test_app
  default_backend default

backend srvs_test
   balance roundrobin
   server webapp01 webapp01.company.com:80 check
   server webapp02 webapp02.company.com:80 check

backend default
   server localhost:80 check
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried with your configuration but I still get 404 errors. The only thing I managed to see in the logs: srvs_test/webapp02 3/0/0/2/9 404 492 - - ---- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /Test/App HTTP/1.1"

Comment: Are you by any chance defining the DNS entry of webapp01 and 02 in your hosts file? Can you try pinging webapp01.company.com from HAProxy and see what you get?

Comment: Weird thing is I do get a response by pinging webapp01 and webapp02. Ended up solving the issue by using the IPs instead of the alias, I still dont understand why it does not work with the alias.

Comment: In my environment pinging the alias `webapp01` would resolve to `webapp01.myorg.local` insead of `.com`. You where defining the FQDN in the HAProxy rule so you need to ensure the FQDN entry resolves, not just he alias. Anyway, glad you resolved the issue :-)